# How to get outline view of Latex Project in Sublime text?

Tags: editor, latex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

As I'm writing Latex more and more on Sublime Text (3), I decide to totally move on to ST from TexnicCenter. However there's one thing I miss from TexnicCenter, that's the ability to show the project in outline view (e.g chapter/subchapter name,...)

For example, writing a long file with one master main.tex file, and each chapter is written in a separate file, TXC gives me this view on the outline panel:

[image]

Can I achieve such thing in ST3? (I know about Ctrl + R but it does not help in this case where the chapters are written separately.)

Comment: Try to search in [packagecontrol](https://packagecontrol.io/search/latex). [LaTeX-Plus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeX-Plus), [LaTeXTools](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXTools), [LaTeXing](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXing) might do the job.

Comment: @JimRaynor Atom  https://atom.io/ now supports this with the document-outline package! The package is pretty easy to customize (I just found it today and was able to add a custom section definition) and will offer more exciting functionality too!

Answer (score 1):

[LaTeXing](http://www.latexing.com) also offers a `SHIFT`+ `Ctrl` + `R` ("Goto Symbol *in Project*").
LaTeXing actually seems to consider all structure markers such as `\chapter{test)`, irrespective of whether they are `\input{}` somewhere, so it's not the real *logical* structure of the document ...

Here's a screen shot:

[image: autocomplete]

It's still not just in the command palette, and not a *real* sidebar of the logical structure *and* there are some confusing duplications ... but still.

Maybe the folks over at [atom latex](https://atom.io/packages/latex) will get on it at some point; atom might be more suited for this kind of flexible UI.

Comment: add this as a feature request on the atom latex repo: https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/issues/105